# Why does Math.floor(1.23456789 * 1e8) / 1e8) return 1.23456788

Tags: java, decimalformat

```
Math.floor(1.23456789 * 1e8) / 1e8)
```

returns:

> 1.23456788

Which is strange considering that:

```
Math.floor(1.23456789 * 1e9) / 1e9)
```

returns:

> 1.23456789

and also

```
Math.floor(1.23456799 * 1e8) / 1e8)
```

returns:

> 1.23456799

Any idea why this is happening and how to avoid it?

Comment: [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java `double` type (almost) conforms to an international standard called IEEE-754, for floating point numbers.  The numbers that can be expressed in this type all have one thing in common - their representations in binary terminate after at most 53 significant digits.

Most numbers with terminating decimal representations do not have terminating binary representations, which means there's no `double` that stores them exactly.  When you write a `double` literal in Java, the value stored in the `double` will generally not be the number you wrote in the literal - instead it will be the nearest available `double`.

The literal `1.23456789` is no exception.  It falls neatly between two numbers that can be stored as `double`, and the exact values of those two `double` numbers are **1.2345678899999998900938180668163113296031951904296875** and **1.23456789000000011213842299184761941432952880859375**.  The rule is that the closer of those two numbers is chosen, so the literal `1.23456789` is stored as **1.2345678899999998900938180668163113296031951904296875**.

The literal `1E8` can be stored exactly as a `double`, so the multiplication in your first example is **1.2345678899999998900938180668163113296031951904296875** times **100000000**, which of course is **123456788.99999998900938180668163113296031951904296875**.  This number can't be stored exactly as a `double`.  The nearest `double` below it is **123456788.99999998509883880615234375** and the nearest `double` above it is **123456789** exactly.  However, the `double` below it is closer, so the value of the Java expression `1.23456789 * 1E8` is actually **123456788.99999998509883880615234375**.  When you apply the `Math.floor` method to this number, the result is exactly **123456788**.

The literal `1E9` can be stored exactly as a `double`, so the multiplication in your second example is **1.2345678899999998900938180668163113296031951904296875** times **1000000000**, which of course is **1234567889.9999998900938180668163113296031951904296875**.  This number can't be stored exactly as a `double`.  The nearest `double` below it is **1234567889.9999997615814208984375** and the nearest double above it is **1234567890** exactly.  But this time, the `double` above it is closer, so the value of the Java expression `1.23456789 * 1E9` is exactly **1234567890**, which is unchanged by the `Math.floor` method.

The second part of your question was how to avoid this.  Well, if you want to do exact calculations involving numbers with terminating decimal representations, you must not store them in `double` variables.  Instead, you can use the `BigDecimal` class, which lets you do things like this

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("1.23456789");
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("100000000");
BigDecimal product = a.multiply(b);
```

and the numbers are represented exactly.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown, that makes sense. I was trying to avoid BigDecimal though as it is really slow...

Answer (score 3):

As answered by Daniel Centore, double precision values are imprecise. Here is a list of the actual values (to 20 digits) for double precision numbers. Shown are the two closest encodings for 1.23456789; the first one is closer. When multiplying by 1e8, the multiply doesn't round up. When multiplying by 1e9, the multiply rounds up to an exact integer value.

```
1.23456789     => 1.2345678899999998901 hex 3ff3c0ca4283de1b
1.23456789     => 1.2345678900000001121 hex 3ff3c0ca4283de1c
1.23456789*1e8 => 123456788.99999998510 hex 419d6f3453ffffff
1.23456789*1e9 => 1234567890.0000000000 hex 41d26580b4800000
```

Answer (score 2):

Floating point arithmetic is imprecise. The conversion to binary and back to decimal can cause problems (as binary cannot perfectly represent decimal fractions and visa-versa) on top of the fact that floating point has limited precision.

You can use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) to get perfect math, but it is much slower. This is only noticable if you will be doing many calculations.

**Edit:** [Here's a `BigDecimal` tutorial.](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2075315/core-java/make-cents-with-bigdecimal.html)